# Moving to the end of a word

Tags: vim

In vim, `e` is supposed to move me to the end of a word.

Let's say I have the following sentence:

`|This is a sentence`

where the `|` indicates my current cursor position.

I would expect that hitting `e` once would get me to the following state:

`This| is a sentence`

but surprisingly I end up with

`Thi|s is a sentence`

– I'm one character before the end of the word.

Consequently, if I hit `ei` to append something to the end of the current word, it ends up putting me into insert mode just before the last character and screwing things up.

Two questions:

- What am I not understanding regarding the `e` motion, what is its use if it puts me just before the last char and not after the last char? What would be an example usage of it?
- How do I quickly accomplish the following: Append something to the end of the word under the cursor

Thanks

Comment: use `ea` to append after the word

Comment: Please run `vimtutor` from the command line

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ei` would be move to the end of the word and *insert*, which would be putting a new character *before* the current last one. `ea` is what you'd want to move to the end and append.

To understand it, suppose you wanted to delete the last character of the word. You'd use `ex`. If `e` moved you past the end of the word, this wouldn't work, and yet you'd expect "move to the end of the word and then delete a character" would be equivalent to "delete the last character of the word". Think of `e` as making the currently selected character (i.e. the one to insert before, or to append after, or to delete, or to switch case, or whatever) the last character of the word. In other words, the cursor is always *on* a character, rather than *between* two characters in the way that many GUI text editors work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the `ex` example helped. I also changed my cursor to be a rectangle, that should help getting used to it.

Answer (score 8):

`e` places you "on top" of the last character. For example, if you then hit `r` and another key, you will replace the character at the cursor position, in this case the last character. If you want to input text *after* the cursor position, use `a` instead of `i`.